# Scan DynamoDB with two filters same column using OR ConditionalOperator

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am sure this is a very noob question, so I apologize up front, but I could not find any examples of where anyone is doing this.

I've create a column lastrun on my table.   I want to find records WHERE it is null or WHERE it is less than x.   I can't figure out how to run this as it seems to only evaluate one of my two conditions because when I put the second condition in the map with the same key for that same column it overwrites my first entry in the map.  What am I missing?

```
         Condition newRunsFilterCondition = new Condition()
    .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.EQ.toString())
    .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withN("0"));

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, -1);

     Condition exRunsFilterCondition = new Condition()
    .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.LT.toString())
    .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withN("" + cal.getTime().getTime()));

    Map<String, Condition> conditions = new HashMap<String, Condition>();
    conditions.put("lastrun", newRunsFilterCondition);
    conditions.put("lastrun", exRunsFilterCondition);

    ScanRequest scanRequest = new ScanRequest()
        .withTableName("DataLoaderSchedule")
        .withScanFilter(conditions).withConditionalOperator("OR");

    ScanResult result = client.scan(scanRequest);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think DynamoDb currently supports 2 filters on the same column today...

```
conditions.put("lastrun", newRunsFilterCondition);
conditions.put("lastrun", exRunsFilterCondition);
```

The `Conditions` variable is a map and currently a single attribute can only be mapped to a single Condition. Thats why you can't have 2 conditions on one column.

The work-around I can think of is you do the scan two times, each time with a different filter. and then merge the results on your side.